# Why the value isn't 0 when the value is less than the button

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i have a simple question that why does this code input for example "500" if my input is 500 when it's suppose to be 0 but when i got over 750 it's suppose to minus that with the input which works perfectly but whenever i input anything lower than 750 it doesn't say 0 it just says the number instead.

```
Function Button() {
        var Fee = document.getElementById("Time").value;
        var Owntax = CountFee(Fee);
        var answer = Fee - Owntax;
        if (Fee > Owntax) {
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "<p>the tax is " + answer.toFixed(2) + "</p>";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "<p>the tax is " + Owntax.toFixed(2) + "</p>";
        }

    }

    function CountFee(Fee) {
        var Owntax = 750;
        if (Fee > Owntax) {
            omavastuu = 750;
        } else {
            Owntax = 0;
        }

        return Owntax;
```

Comment: Fee is a string, not a number

Comment: What is `TravelFee` in `var Owntax = CountFee(TravelFee);`

Comment: Oh it's the Fee sorry

Comment: Changing it to parseint did not help @epascarello

Comment: @Leo665, please make the replacement (Travel fee => Fee)